# Defined constant for max sequential integer that can be stored in a float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++17, precision, c++20

Is there a defined constant in the C++ standard, for largest sequential integer that can be stored in a float without approximation?
(and also double, and long double?)

Is this directly related to the number of mantissa bits/significand bits?
If so, would the max sequential integer be exactly `(1 << mantissaBitCount) - 1` ?
Is there a defined constant in the C++ standard, for the mantissa bit count for float, double, and long double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a defined constant in the C++ standard, for the mantissa bit count for float, double, and long double?

Yes. They are in the `std::numeric_limits` template. There are also macros for these inherited from the C standard library.

> Is [max sequential integer] directly related to the number of mantissa bits/significand bits?

Yes.

> If so, would the max sequential integer be exactly `(1 << mantissaBitCount) - 1` ?

Not quite. Remove the -1 and this would be true for representations that use radix of 2 (which is common). Note that `mantissaBitCount` is assumed to be the number of bits in the true significand rather than number of bits in the memory i.e. in case of IEEE-754 it includes the implicit leading bit.

> Defined constant for max sequential integer that can be stored in a float?

There is no such constant, but it can be calculated using the provided constants:

```
using T = float; // as an example; works with other types too (even integers)
using limits = std::numeric_limits<T>;
constexpr int digits = limits::digits;
constexpr int radix = limits::radix;
constexpr T max_conseq = std::pow(radix, T(digits));
```

Comment: @Giffyguy No need for the -1

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused again. If there's an `implicit leading bit` and the significand is let's say 8 bits, wouldn't the max integer value with the implicit leading bit be `1 1111 1111`, which still has a `-1` going on? (Not 1 0000 0000)

Comment: @Giffyguy Just add 1 to that number. The significand goes to 0 and exponent increases by 1. Now, after this adding 1 to significand would increase the represented value by 2.

Comment: The exponent increases by 1, and the value is still only one integer away! Yes! (minor mind-blowing experience) Okay now I understand for sure. Thank you so much, again!

Comment: We might prefer to avoid `pow` because it is sometimes implemented poorly. `scalbn` is more likely to produce a good result, but the value can also be calculated with a simple division, both shown in my answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm literally in the process of writing some meta-programming using templates, to make `pow` functional for compile-time constexprs. http://timmurphy.org/2013/06/27/template-metaprogramming-in-c/ Your methods might actually be better though. Great tip.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree. Pow is mathematically the operation, but `std::scalbn` is indeed better for the special case of radix.

Comment: What's your honest opinion of the solution in my answer? Is it a good idea, or not?

Comment: @eerorika Corner case: `scalbn()` apparently does not round when forming a result in the [0.0 to  DBL/FLT_MIN) range. `pow()` does.

Answer (score 2):

The integer before the first unrepresentable integer in type `T` may be calculated as either of:

- `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix / std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()`, or
- `std::scalbn(1, std::numeric_limits<T>::digits)`.

This is because that integer is *b* <sup>*p*</sup>, where *b* is the radix used for the floating-point format, and *p* is the precision, the number of digits in the significand. This is because if all the digits of the significand are at their maximum value (*b*−1), and the exponent is such that it just scales the significand to an integer, the value represented is  *b* <sup>*p*</sup>−1 (such as 999 for three digits in base ten). The next integer, *b* <sup>*p*</sup> is also obviously representable, with significand 1 and exponent *p*. The integer after that is not, as, in base *b*, it would have a 1 followed by *p*−1 0s followed by a 1, which does not fit in a significand of *p* digits.

Regarding the second expression: The `scalbn` function, declared in `<cmath>`, multiplies its first operand by *b* to the power of the second operand. `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` is the *p* described above, so that `scalbn` expression produces *b* <sup>*p*</sup>.

Regarding the first expression: `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix` is *b*, and `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` is the position value of the lowest position in the significand for the floating-point number 1, so it is *b* <sup>*p*−1</sup>, so dividing these produces *b* <sup>*p*</sup>.

Comment: Note: the `epsilon()` version is valid for assigning `constexpr` constants, while the `scalbn` is not. My answer is another potential option for `constexpr` compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I wrote using recursive template metaprogramming.
This uses the `pow`-based formula from [eerorika's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996071/120888), while hopefully avoiding potential problems caused by poor implementations of `pow`.

The recursive template metaprogramming is [explained here](http://timmurphy.org/2013/06/27/template-metaprogramming-in-c/).

This solution is valuable, because it guarantees `constexpr` results.

```
//recursive template, which references itself
template <class result_T, result_T B, uint64_t E>
constexpr result_T const pow_ = B * pow_<result_T, B, E - 1>;

//"base case" template (partial specialization),
//which ends the recursion so it doesn't loop forever
template <class result_T, result_T B>
constexpr result_T const pow_<result_T, B, 0> = static_cast<result_T>(1);

//friendly constants for max sequential integer values, for floating-point types
constexpr uint32_t const FLOAT_MAX_SEQ_INT =
    pow_<uint32_t, numeric_limits<float>::radix, numeric_limits<float>::digits>;

constexpr uint64_t const DOUBLE_MAX_SEQ_INT =
    pow_<uint64_t, numeric_limits<double>::radix, numeric_limits<double>::digits>;

constexpr long double const LONG_DOUBLE_MAX_SEQ_INT =
    pow_<long double, numeric_limits<long double>::radix, numeric_limits<long double>::digits>;
```